# Automapper Custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level individual members on a type

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, automapper

I am trying to map a result I get from database and I have the following models

```
public class ClientTest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ClientTestDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ClientDbItem
{
    public ClientTest Client { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

and the following mapping

```
CreateMap<ClientTest, ClientTestDto>();

CreateMap<ClientDbItem, ClientTestDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Client));
```

When I run the software I get

> Custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level
>   individual members on a type

Why is that happening If I am creating the config for ClientTest and ClientTestDto first?

Comment: This is sample code. I have dozens of these cases with models that are not so small :D

Comment: @Fabio it is not about speed.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Thanks that did the trick. Create an answer post so I can mark it as answer

Comment: CodeProject - AutoMapper

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61629/AutoMapper

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's a special API for that, `IncludeMembers`. See [here](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers).

Answer (score 0):

This error might also arise when you try to map the top-level element to a constructor:

```
    .ForMember(dest => dest, opt => opt.MapFrom(
        src => new B1(src.Prop3, src.Prop4)));
```

Instead of mapping the top-level element **MEMBER** to the constructor (which works fine):

```
    .ForMember(dest => dest.MyProperty, opt => opt.MapFrom(
        src => new B1(src.Prop3, src.Prop4)));
```

To avoid this, use **.ForCtorParam**

Example:

```
CreateMap<Source, DestinationWithConstructor>()
.ForCtorParam("code", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Prop3))
.ForCtorParam("text", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Prop4))
```