# Flattening relational entities with AutoMapper

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

I have following situation in EntityFramework Context:

```
class File {
   string FileName { get;set; }
   virtual ICollection<CaseFile> CaseFiles {get;set;}
}
class Case {
   string CaseRef { get;set; }
   virtual ICollection<CaseFile> CaseFiles {get;set;}
}
class CaseFile {
   virtual Case
   virtual File
}
```

And we're setting up AutoMapper, but we do not want to expose the CaseFile model, our ViewModel is following:

```
class CaseViewModel {
   IEnumerable<FileViewModel> Files { get; set; }
}
```

AutoMapper Profile:

```
class CaseMappingProfile {
   public CaseMappingProfile() {
      CreateMap<Case, CaseViewModel>();
      CreateMap<File, FileViewModel>();
      CreateMap<CaseFile, FileViewModel>();
   }
}
```

Now, I can't really find a way to map the CaseFile to a FileViewModel and tell AutoMapper to use the CaseFile.File property as source. I realize I could simply do this:

```
      CreateMap<CaseFile, FileViewModel>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Prop1, src => src.File.Prop1)
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Prop2, src => src.File.Prop2)
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Prop3, src => src.File.Prop3);
```

But the File entity is connected to a lot of other entities, not just case as the example.
And I would hate having to do this for every single relational entity.

```
      CreateMap<CaseFile, FileViewModel>()
      .ForPath(dest => dest, src => src.File);
```

is not allowed, you need to target a destination member, you can not target the model itself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59389445/automapper-custom-configuration-for-members-is-only-supported-for-top-level-indi/59390372#59390372

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should need a map for the CaseFile.

If the CaseViewModel will contain a collection of FileViewModels then:

```
CreateMap<File, FileViewModel>()
CreateMap<Case, CaseViewModel>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Files, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CaseFiles.Select(c => c.File).ToList()));
```

Provided the FileViewModel does not have a collection of Cases Automapper should be resolving the file to the FileViewModel. If other areas want a File view model /w Cases then you would need two view models for Case and File respectively. One with the child collection, and one without. I.e. CaseViewModel contains a collection of  FileChildViewModels (which don't have collections of cases defined) while FileViewModel contains CaseChildViewModels. The "child" flavours exclude the child collections to serve as children themselves.