# Automapper mapping to properties from a nested object

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper

i have an issue with mapping from source a class that has properties which are in a nested object of a parent class to be mapped to destination a class which have no nested objects.

This is my destination class

```
 public class SCS_OUT_Manifest 
    {
      
        public string ShipperAddress1 { get; set; }
        public string ShipperAddress2 { get; set; }
        public string ShipperAddress3 { get; set; }
       
    }
```

This is my Source class

```
public class CreateManifestFromToDto
    {
        public CreateManifestShipperDetailsDto From { get; set; }
    }
    
      public class CreateManifestShipperDetailsDto
    {

        public string ShipperAddress1 { get; set; }
        public string ShipperAddress2 { get; set; }
        public string ShipperAddress3 { get; set; }
    }
```

I tried something like below, but does not work.

```
 CreateMap<CreateManifestFromToDto, SCS_OUT_Manifest>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest, src => src.MapFrom(s => s.From));
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59389445/automapper-custom-configuration-for-members-is-only-supported-for-top-level-indi/59390372#59390372

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, thats exaclty what i was looking for. it worked. thanks lot. how can i marke this comment as the answer?

Comment: Just add a plus one to the answer over there.

Comment: hi @sddk, its the same link whcih lucianBargaoanu has provided. thanks